# How do I install a virtual environment in python as a beginner

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.10

I'm new to programming and i see lots of post saying you have to create a virtual environment for better experience while working on a python project, and i can't really wrap my head on that.....
First question, why do I need a virtual environment?
Secondly, what happens if i don't use one
Also, how do I install it what are the necessary procedures for a beginner
Lastly, how do I know I'm using a virtual environment in python, like how do I tell the difference or there is none??

Hoping to get answers

Comment: read this https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html  you actually only need to read the first section. before you get to the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why do I need a virtual environment?

Because a virtual environment will prevent clashes if you have several applications requiring different versions of Python, or different versions of some Python packages.
You might not run into such issues as a beginner, but it's a good habit to have, nevertheless.

> what happens if I don't use one?

You might have an application, which is unable to run, because of conflicting requirements.

> how do I install it?

Running `python3 -m venv my-app` will create the directory `my-app`, containing a virtual environment.
After creating a virtual environment, you can activate it with `source my-app/bin/activate` on Unix, or macOS, and with `my-app/Scripts/activate.bat` on Windows.

> how do I know I'm using a virtual environment?

If you're using a virtual environment your prompt will show its name, e.g. `(my-app) $`.

See also the section [Virtual Environments, and Packages, from The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: Okay, now I get it. But whenever I try running python3 -m venv my-app, it keeps saying python was not found: run without arguments  to install from the Microsoft store, or disable this shortcut from settings> Managed App Execution Aliases. @Dani